# Asking for basic C++ syntax specifics; using & inside initialization vs outside initialization

Tags: c++

So, I know that someone writing C++ code can do this:

```
    double *doublePtr;             // Declares a pointer.
    double doubleVal = 8.234;      // Declares and initializes a double.
    doublePtr = &doubleVal;        // Makes pointer point to doubleVal.
```

Also, someone writing C++ code could do something like this:

```
    double doubleVal = 8.234;      // Declares and initializes a double.
    double &doubleRef = doubleVal; // Declares/Initializes a reference
                                   // To the address of doubleVal (???).
                                   // But why isn't doubleVal instead
                                   // &doubleVal if it's an address that
                                   // &doubleRef is being initialized with.
```

So, why is it not appropriate (due to compiler error) to do this:

```
    double dVala = 1.234, dValb = 3.456;
    &dVala = &dValb;
```

More specifically, I'm trying to ask the question of, "What is it that I'm confused about that, with a simple explanation, will make the specifics of this more clear". Are references to the built in data types of C++ constants, so that they can only be initialized with a value, but cannot be changed anytime after they are initialized?

Of course, we can output the value of the address of a variable to some data type like this:

```
    double dVala = 23.456;
    cout << &dVala;
```

I hope that my questions are clear. Thanks.

Comment: The reference isn't to the address of doubleVal, think of references as variable aliases

Comment: The main thing to understand is that & is something completely different when it's part of a _type_ (a _type-id_ in the text of the standard) vs when it's part of an _expression_

Comment: You're not allowed to change the memory location of `dVala`, which is essentially what you're trying to do with `&dVala = &dValb;`  That location is set at compile time.

Comment: You can't obviously modify a memory address.

Comment: @ChrisBeck You mean, in other words, the role of & changes when it's next to a type vs. when it's inside of an expression? What would that difference be exactly?

Comment: @awesomeyi Do you mean, don't think of pointers as references? Just simply take a reference variable as another means of referring to the same thing. Like when we pass variables by reference to functions, maybe?

Comment: @Carlton I think there's plenty more specifics about compile time I am unaware of. I guess if we could change the memory location after compile time, this would be bad, because then we could access some other place in memory that would be vital to some other application, and this could cause a major crash. Is this correct?

Comment: @zenith Well, when you put it that way, my question does seem really silly, and it becomes pretty obvious to what the answer is. However, I feel like your answer and Carlton's answer are perhaps slightly different maybe. I took your answer as trying to change the physical address of the physical memory itself. Like if I were to change my home address to a different address. Or is it more like what Carlton had said, that after compile time, that specific memory is reserved to a purpose, and you cannot change it at run time for obvious reasons? Just want to be clear.

Comment: @user3499524 Yes. Pointers are not references at all.

Comment: And thanks everyone, things are starting to become more clear. Maybe another way to make the question more clear is to go back to this example:

        double doubleVal = 8.234;.
        double &doubleRef = doubleVal;

So, in the first line, doubleVal is simply an alias to the address that stores 8.234. Then, in the next line, doubleRef is just ANOTHER alias to the address that stores 8.234. We're not changing any addresses here during run time. That's why this is okay. But I still think that:

        double &doubleRef = doubleVal;

Isn't as clear as:

        double &doubleRef = &doubleVal;

Comment: @user3499524: That's basically right. It breaks down a little when you consider how C++ compilers are actually implemented and how your program works on a real, physical machine, but C++ the language is an abstraction and in terms of that abstraction you are basically right. Your suggested code is how pointers work. There's no point in having references if they're just going to be carbon copies of pointers. References are a more abstract concept, and quite deliberately so. However the truth is that your compiler probably implements them as pointers when not optimised away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The symbol `&` has multiple meanings depending on context: you can't just take it from one place, put it another place, and expect the exact same thing to happen.

1. When used as an operator between two expressions, it is a bitwise AND.
2. When decorating a typename, it means "reference-to".
3. When preceding an expression, it means "address-of".

- Your first working example declares a pointer and doesn't initialise it, but later assigns to it the address of an object.
- Your second working example declares and initialises a reference to an object.
- Your broken example attempts to assign the address of one thing to the address of another thing. It just has no meaning.

Aside from that:

> Are references to the built in data types of C++ constants, so that they can only be initialized with a value, but cannot be changed anytime after they are initialized?

Yes. *All* references are themselves immutable, and cannot be re-seated after initialisation.

As we've explored above, writing `&someReference` doesn't actually "access" the reference itself; indeed, there is no syntax that exists to do so.

> But why isn't doubleVal instead &doubleVal if it's an address that &doubleRef is being initialized with.

Because then references would be largely indistinguishable from pointers, and thus pointless (lol).

Don't read a `double& doubleRef` as something called `&doubleRef`. It's not. It's a `double&` called `doubleRef`.

References "do the dereferencing for you". They bind directly to objects without you needing to take the address yourself.

This is a gift of the language.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would find it very enlightening to learn some basic assembly.  That way you can see exactly how your C++ code is being expressed in the native language of your CPU.  To help you understand what's going on with your code, let's break it down into assembly.  This is what I got from MSVC2013 with all optimizations turned off.  Each block represents one line of your original code:

```
double doubleVal = 8.234;
movsd   xmm0,mmword ptr [test!_real (00000001`3f2948b8)]
movsd   mmword ptr [rsp],xmm0

doublePtr = &doubleVal;
lea     rax,[rsp]
mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rax

double &doubleRef = doubleVal;
lea     rax,[rsp]
mov     qword ptr [rsp+10h],rax
```

What's not shown here is that the compiler has set up the code in such a way that there is space for three variables in memory.  The first is your variable `doublVal`, which is at a memory address stored in the CPU register `rsp`.  Similarly, `doublePtr` and `doubleRef` are stored at `rsp+8` and `rsp+10h` (these are hexadecimal values, btw).  This spacing reflects the fact that the variables are 8 bytes long.

Now, the first two instructions (`movsd`) move a constant value (8.234) into a floating point register, then move it to the address stored in `rsp` (the location of `doubleVal`).  Now `doubleVal` is initialized to the constant you specified.

The next block takes the address of `doubleVal` (stored in `rsp`) and copies it to the CPU register `rax`, then copies that value in `rax` to the address `rsp+8` (the location of `doublePtr`).  Now `doublePtr` has been initialized with the address of `doubleVal`.

The third block is identical to the second one, with the exception that `doubleVal`'s address is instead copied into the variable `doubleRef` (whose address is stored in `rsp+10h`).  This shows that the compiler implemented your reference variable using pointers, which is fairly typical.